# Press button, start native email program with attachment (located on webserver)

Tags: javascript, email, button, webserver, attachment

I have tried all different versions of send email however I have not yet achieved the following:

Javascript (or HTML) button, when pressed, open native mail application with attachment. The attachment is located on the same server as the webpage ex.:

- web: `www.something.com`
- file: `www.something.com/file.pdf`

The solution should not include serverside scripting (ASP/PHP)
I need a simple snippet to make this happen :) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible, you have to send a email from a server which can attach it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standardized way to do this, but some email clients accept:

```
a href="mailto:youremail@email.com?attachment=<your filepath>"
```

where  would have to be something like "C://Inetpub/wwwroot/myfile.pdf"

However, it will only attach something from the client's machine. You can't attach a file from the web.

Another option would be to just include a link to the file in the body of your email, or instructions to the user on how to email their attachment.

Comment: To bad the whole idea is to attach something from the web (my webserver). I have tried the various snippets for attaching files from clients but know I need to be able to send files stored on the web :)

Comment: Just a thought, would you be able to attach a file through ftp? (ex. ftp://ftp.something.com/file.pdf)?

Comment: Yeah - there's no good way to attach a file from the web, or through FTP. Your best bet might be to include a link in the email. Otherwise, you can include instructions to the user on your webpage on how to download and attach the file themselves.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be what you're looking for, but you can send arguments to native e-mail client using the "mailto:" reference.

For example, you can set the default subject with:

`<a href="mailto:your@email.com?subject=complaint">`

see more at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

so you can send the link to the attachment with

`<a href="mailto:your@email.com?body=the attached file is at this link: %link%">`

Comment: Yeah, I am able to open my native email client using something like that :) But the real problem would be to attach a web stored file