# unable to add image into email using ui5/javascript

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to send a vizframe to email, to achieve this I converted the chart into an image. but I am unable to add this image to my email.

I can do same thing for text but not for an image.

i.e.: new sap.m.Text({text: "stackoverflow"}).getText() does the job for me.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI5 only allows you to trigger the email client and pre-populate some *plain text fields*. You can check out the documentation for the [URLHelper](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.URLHelper.html#triggerEmail) class.

If you also want to add an attachment (the picture), I don't think you will be able to. Check out this other question on StackOverflow: [Automatically open default email client and pre-populate content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231125/automatically-open-default-email-client-and-pre-populate-content). The only "good" way of doing it seems to be to just include a link towards your image inside the mail (assuming that the image is accessible via a URL).

Based on this question [Press button, start native email program with attachment (located on webserver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657888/press-button-start-native-email-program-with-attachment-located-on-webserver) it seems that some clients *might* allow you to specify the local path to the image (but in UI5 I don't see how you would know a path on the local machine).

Comment: I have the image in form of base64 url, but ms outlook doesn't support base64 url.
so now I need to somehow put it as inline image in the email.